# A question about a measure defined using two CDF's

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, definition

I know that the sum of measures is a measure (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805857/countable-sum-of-measures-is-a-measure)). However, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables with CDF's $F_1$ and $F_2$, respectively, I know that
$$F = F_1 + F_2$$
is *not even* a CDF ( in fact, the CDF of $Z = X_1+X_2$ is given by the convolution of $F_1*F_2$. See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455979/convolution-of-distribution-functions) ).

Moreover, given a CDF $F$, I also know that I can define measures, for example, as
$$\nu(E):= \int_E h(x) dF(x), \quad E \,\, \hbox{any borelian.}$$
In this case I have
\begin{equation}\label{I}\tag{I}
d\nu(x)=h(x)dF(x)
\end{equation}

So I can 'change' the measures:
$$\int g(x)dF(x) = \int \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} d\nu(x)$$
So, my question is related to the following measure:
\begin{equation}\label{kasjkjas}\tag{M}
\nu(E) = \sum_{i=1}^2 \int_E |x|^2 dF_i(x)
\end{equation}

So I'm dying to interchange the integral and the sum:
\begin{equation}\label{II}\tag{II}
\nu(E) =  \int_E |x|^2 dF(x), \quad dF(x):= \sum_{i=1}^2 dF_i(x)
\end{equation}

But I don't know if this is mathematically rigorous. The impression I get is that I'm treating $F_1 + F_2$ as a CDF, which is not true. Moreover, as in (\ref{I})
$$d\nu(x)= |x|^2 dF(x) = |x|^2 [dF_1(x)+dF_2(x)]$$
So is it correct to define $dF(x)$ as in (\ref{II}) even though $F_1+F_2$ is not well defined?

If this is not correct, how can we rewrite the following integral in terms of $dF_1(x)$ and $dF_2(x)$:
$$\int f(x) \frac{1}{|x|^2} d\nu(x)\,\,\,\,?$$
(If (\ref{II}) is correct, ignore this last question )

**Attempt after comments**

According to Snoop's comments, setting $\quad dF(x):= \sum_{i=1}^2 dF_i(x)$ is mathematically incorrect. So, I define
$$\nu_i (E):= \int_E |x|^2 dF_i(x), \quad i =1,2$$
It implies
$$d\nu_i(x)= |x|^2 dF_i(x), \quad i =1,2$$
So substituting in (\ref{kasjkjas}), we have:
$$\nu(E)= \int_E d\nu_1(x)+ \int_E d\nu_2(x)= \nu_1(E)+\nu_2(E)$$
Moreover $d\nu= d(\nu_1 + \nu_2)= d\nu_1 + d\nu_2$. So,
$$\int f(x) \frac{1}{|x|^2} d\nu(x) = \int f(x) \frac{1}{|x|^2} (d\nu_1(x) + d\nu_2(x)) = \int f(x) \frac{1}{|x|^2} d\nu_1(x) + \int f(x) \frac{1}{|x|^2}  d\nu_2(x)$$

So we conclude
$$\int f(x) \frac{1}{|x|^2} d\nu(x) = \sum_{i=1}^2 \int f(x) dF_i(x) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu,\nu$ be finite measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and define $\rho:=\mu+\nu$. (1): We prove that $\rho$ is a finite measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ by checking $\rho(\emptyset)=0,\rho(\mathbb{R})<\infty$ and countable additivity; this is [straightforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805857/countable-sum-of-measures-is-a-measure). (2): let $u \geq 0$ and $u \in L^1(\mu)\cap L^1(\nu)$; we have a sequence of nonnegative simple functions $u_n\uparrow u$ so
$$\begin{aligned}\int u d\mu+\int ud\nu&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg(\int u_nd\mu+\int u_nd\nu\bigg)=\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg(\sum_{k\leq N_n}\phi_{k}^n(\mu(A_k^n)+\nu(A_k^n))\bigg)=\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k\leq N_n}\phi_{k}^n\rho(A_k^n)=\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int u_nd\rho=\\
&\stackrel{\textrm{MCT}}{=}\int ud\rho\end{aligned}$$
This implies $u \in L^1(\rho)$. In your case, $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures with respective cdfs $F_1,F_2$ and $|x|^2 \in L^1(\mu)\cap L^1(\nu)$ is a reasonable further assumption.

Comment: Are you saying that  $\mu(E)= \int_E |x|^2 dF_1(x)$ and $\nu(E)= \int_E |x|^2 dF_2(x)$ .    If Yes, how to conclude $dF(x):= \sum_{i=1}^2 dF_i(x)$ is well defined? I still don't understand because $F_1 + F_2 $ is not a CDF.

Comment: My biggest concern is whether I'm making a grotesque mistake in writing $dF(x)= dF_1(x)+dF_2(x)$.

Comment: @AndréGoulart I am describing a general case with probability measures $\mu,\nu$. Of course $\rho$ is not a probability measure. I have shown that $d\mu+d\nu=d(\mu + \nu)=d\rho$ (in the sense of Lebesgue integrals). You seem to be working with [these integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) but there is no need for that; cdfs extend to unique probability measures.

Comment: I also find (repeated) gratuitous downvoting rude, whoever it is

Comment: Dear, thanks for the reply and suggestions. I'm new to measurement theory, but I'll try to correct my mistake.

Comment: Fixed the annoying downvote.

Comment: Dear, I think that following his suggestions, I managed to solve my problem. Thanks. If there are any errors, I would appreciate you letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

$F_1+F_2$ is not a cdf (since the measure of the whole space is two) but it is a distribution function (right continuous, non decreasing).

Every right continuous, non decreasing function $F$ defines a unique (Lebesgue Stieltjes) measure $\mu_F$ on ${\cal B}$, the Borel sets, such that $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b)-F(a)$.

It follows that $\mu_{F_1+F_2} = \mu_{F_1} + \mu_{F_2}$.

The usual sequence (indicator functions, simple functions, integrable limits) shows that
$\int f d\mu_{F_1+F_2} = \int f d  \mu_{F_1} + \int f d \mu_{F_2}$.

Addendum:

Given the definition of $\nu_k$ above, we have
$\int g d \nu_k = \int g(x) |x|^2 d\mu_{F_k} (x)$ and so (assuming integrability as appropriate) we have
$\int f(x) {1 \over |x|^2} d  \nu_k(x) = \int f(x) d\mu_{F_k}(x)$. Summing gives the desired result.

Comment: Dear, thanks for the reply. I had already validated the other user's answer, but your answer will be considered. I will read and comment if I have any questions and comments.

Comment: @AndréGoulart Don't worry, I don't care about rep (other than $-1$s :-)).

Comment: If $dF(x)= \sum_{i=1}^2 dF_i(x)$ and $d\nu(x)= |x|^2 \sum_{i=1}^2 dF_i(x)$ are wrong, why
$$\int f(x)\frac{1}{|x|^2}d\nu(x)= \int f(x) \sum_{i=1}^2 dF_i(x) =\sum_{i=1}^2 \int f(x) dF_i(x)$$

works? Although I believe I have solved my problem more rigorously, my question is now more notational.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last question?

Comment: Note that your answer necessarily needs to go through the definition of the measures $\mu_{F_k}$. I was getting the same result but in a more direct way, without needing to define $\mu_{F_k}$. See my last question as you referred. What's wrong, strictly speaking?